# Center an image horizontally with CSS, on top of a background video

Tags: html, css

New to coding.
I've set a video to autoplay on the background of a website.
When I try to place an image on top, I encounter issues, specifically when attempting to center it horizontally.

The typical solution results in the image disappearing:

```
img.center {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is my CSS for the logo:

```
.logo {
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   height: 250px;
   padding-top: 15px;
}
```

I need this logo to float on top of the background video with it styled as such:

```
#bgvideo {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple as this. Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/alecdesjardins/pen/WywrRK).

HTML:

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<img id="myImg" src="https://www.searchenginegenie.com/images/29-samplelogo.jpg" width="200">
```

CSS:

```
#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
}
#myImg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: auto; 
}
```

Comment: Hi alec, thanks for your reply. This works however the image fills the whole screen. When i resize the width down to 300px, it then moves the image halfway down the screen. any solutions? thanks

Comment: @JackScott yes hold on, I jumped the gun on this one, I'll get you a working solution.

Comment: its okay i did a bit of trouble shooting and fixed it, just had to change the second translate parameter to -110%... is this a good fix?

Comment: @JackScott is your video supposed to be fixed, so that way you can still see it when you scroll?

Comment: yeah, but when i scroll i want the rest of the website to appear over the top of it. i've got that working ok. but now there's a small issue where the site is slightly bigger than 100% of the browser window...

Comment: checked the solution, this works for centering the object, but it still displays about 50% down the webpage. so i've done 
  transform: translate(0%, -60%);

Comment: @JackScott not sure what you mean, don't you want the logo to appear centered inside it?

Comment: I just want it centered horizontally, not vertically

Comment: @JackScott oh I understand, so just centered horizontally over the top of the video

Comment: @JackScott removed `top: 0`  and `bottom: 0`

Comment: works perfectly! thanks so much alec. any ideas on why the webpage scrolls horizontally slightly?

Comment: @JackScott that would have to do with how your content is being displayed, I doubt it has anything to do with the video and logo, also could you accept the answer to help others?

Comment: done. & yes for some reason the 'about us' container has a slight left indent... can't find why its doing that

Comment: @JackScott I would say use your developer console in your browser and inspect the element. I can't be much help without seeing the code. That developer console should help a lot, you can test changes (style attributes) on the fly and see their effects.